# Driver for toshiba laptop

Tags: drivers

Toshiba satellite c640-x4014.Is ubuntu compatible with my laptop?
so please help me with this,or any other Linux OS available for the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Ubuntu is compatible with most computers, even old ones. According to [this website](http://compareindia.ibnlive.com/specification/laptops/toshiba-satellite-c640x4014/270492) the specs are good, apart from the RAM, only 2GB. Not sure if so little RAM will be an issue, just install Ubuntu on it, and see how it performs. If it performs poorly, you could try Lubuntu, which is a more "lightweight" distro.